# Android studio emulator not responding

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to open the android studio emulator, but not responding.
This alert appears:
[Alert Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPIor.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix that problem, I had to updated my 2010 graphics driver to driver not older than from 2012, as Genymotion support team says!
Thank you :)