# Genymotion virtual devices not working

Tags: android, genymotion

I can't open the virtual devices on genymotion!
The problems shows as the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkqoN.jpg).
I've HP G62-460SS Notebook PC, Windows 7 32-bit and the Graphics driver updated.
Could you please help me to make it run.
Thank you!

Comment: Just don't use Genymotion

Comment: What can I use instead of genymotion? Because I've the same issue on android studio emulator [Android studio emulator not responding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804817/android-studio-emulator-not-responding)!
Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Genymotion support team answer me with that email:

> Genymotion heavily relies on your hardware, OS and drivers (for more
>   details, please read Genymotion requirements).
>
> If they are not recent enough, we regret we cannot guarantee the
>   proper operation of Genymotion on your system. We recommend using a
>   workstation not older than from 2012.
>
> Your CPU is an Intel® Core™ i3-350M Processor (3M Cache, 2.26 GHz) :
>   Q1'10

Is there any chance to update my graphics driver to version older than 2012?